# Cannot update module Base odoo 10

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-10

I try to run odoo10 with only addons base , but every time base/base_date.xml is loading the error show up, I `-i init` new database or try old database and update base module with `-u base` is same result, maybe some wrong version of lib.

```
2021-08-26 18:22:51,873 64535 INFO odoo10 odoo.modules.registry: module base: creating or updating database tables
2021-08-26 18:22:53,179 64535 INFO odoo10 odoo.modules.loading: loading base/res/res.lang.csv
2021-08-26 18:22:53,658 64535 INFO odoo10 odoo.modules.loading: loading base/base_data.xml
2021-08-26 18:22:53,671 64535 ERROR odoo10 odoo.models: Exception while validating constraint
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/viet/odoo-10.0/odoo/models.py", line 1081, in _validate_fields
    check(self)
  File "/home/viet/odoo-10.0/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 279, in _check_xml
    view_arch = etree.fromstring(encode(view.arch))
  File "src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx", line 3213, in lxml.etree.fromstring (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:82934)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1819, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:124533)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1707, in lxml.etree._parseDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:123074)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1079, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:117114)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 573, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:110510)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 683, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:112276)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 613, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:111124)
XMLSyntaxError: Extra content at the end of the document, line 5, column 13
2021-08-26 18:22:53,674 64535 WARNING odoo10 odoo.modules.loading: Transient module states were reset
2021-08-26 18:22:53,674 64535 ERROR odoo10 odoo.modules.registry: Failed to load registry
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/viet/odoo-10.0/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 83, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
```

Comment: This error `XMLSyntaxError: Extra content at the end of the document, `. This implies one of the XML documents has syntax errors.
You can upgrade all modules and check when upgrading what module does the error come up
Other than that, check your most recent updated custom modules for the error.

Comment: i only have addons base odoo 10, no custom module, if error in base/base_data.xml seem like it cannot be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find the answer, it seems the lxml library for generate the xml file is broken reinstall that :

```
 pip uninstall lxml
 pip install lxml==3.5.0
```

and less library for Js error.

```
npm uninstall -g less
npm install -g less@3.10.3
```